# MVC4: Does global.asax being called first before the core assembly get loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does global.asax being called first before the core assembly get loaded?

The core assembly is the project dll. Which one get called first when starting up MVC application?

What is happening when the application is starting up? What is the sequence of events that happened when MVC application starting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute**

This [new attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) allows you to have code run way early in the ASP.NET pipeline as an application starts up. I mean way early, even before Application_Start.

This happens to also be before code in your App_code folder (assuming you have any code in there) has been compiled.

For more information take a look at this [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/) here is a good blog about this after PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute Application_Start method of Global.asax called.

Comment: Does this preApplicationStartMethodAttribute run before the main assembly being loaded? Because the code will be written inside the compiled assembly right?

Comment: Yes that's right it will run before the main assembly being loaded even before App_Code folder has been compiled.